# Extracting UID from ODBC Connection in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access front end with tables linked to SQL Server. I used a file DSN to link tables, and upon opening Access database the user has to enter SQL server userID and password.

Is there a way to extract that userID (not the password) from the established ODBC connection, for example to use it for display and audit purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Pass-Through query in Access with just the statement...

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER
```

...then in the Property Sheet for that query click the ellipsis button beside `ODBC Connect Str` and select your File DSN. (When asked if you want to save the password in the connection string, say "No".)

Then save the Pass-Through query (I called mine "getCurrentSqlUser") and run it to get the name of the current user on the SQL server.

(Note: While testing this I logged in as `sa` and found that the query returned `dbo`. I think that's because I was logged in as a member of the `sysadmin` Server Role.)